# Problems using java HttpsURLConnection to download with authorization

Tags: java

I am trying to download file from a https website using java HttpsURLConnection with the Authorization header. I keep getting back the 401 response code, however, I don't have a problem using the credentials to download it through a web browser. Please help to take a look what might be wrong with my code:

```
File file = new File("c:/filename"); 
String src = "https://www.example.com/filename";
try {
    file.createNewFile();       
    URL url = new URL(src);
    HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();


    String userCredentials = "username:password";
    String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(userCredentials.getBytes()));
    urlConnection.addRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);
    urlConnection.connect();

    System.out.println("code" + urlConnection.getResponseCode());

    InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    int d;
    while ((d = in.read()) != -1) {
        out.write(d);
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Failed to get the file from source. " + e);
    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be using `java.net.Authenticator`.

Comment: Thanks, EJP! I give it a try